# Regex - match between 1st and last occurrence of double square brackets

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I'm looking to match any text and non text values, located within **" "** , but only between the 1st and the last instance of **[[** and **]]**

> window.google.ac.h(["text",**[[**"text1",0],["text2",0,[3]],["text3",0],["text4",0,[3]],["text5",0],["text6",0],["text7",0
>   **]]**,{"q":"hygjgjhbjh","k":1}])

So far I've managed to get some results (far from ideal) by using: "(.*?)",0
The issue I have is the it either matches all the way until

> "text4",0,[3]]

or starts matching at

> ["text",

I only need to match *text1 text2 text3 .. text7*

Notes: double square bracket position and nr of instances, between the 1st and the last is not consistent.

Thanks for your help guys!

Edit: I'm using http://regexr.com/ to test it

Comment: In which language/tool you're doing this?

Comment: Hi, I'm using http://regexr.com/ to test it. That's for Excel VBA, thanks.

Comment: @Sam In that case my answer should work, because VBA uses the .NET regex engine.

Comment: (?<=\[\[.*)"(.+?)"(?=.*\]\]) - VBA gives compile error'expected end of statement'and I'm unable to test using regexr.com The closest I've managed to get on regexr.com is:\[.[a-z\\0-9 /.'_-]+.,(.|....)\] , which seems to work in my VBA except in some cases (e.g. when the order of double brackets changes). I then use additional functions to clean it up, so, again, not ideal..

Answer (score 2):

Well, you didn't say which language, but using .NET regex (which largely follows the Perl standard), the first match groups of all the matches of a global match using the following regex will contain the values you want:

```
(?<=\[\[.*)"(.+?)"(?=.*\]\])
```

A global match on `"(.+?)"` alone would return matches whose first match groups would contain the characters between the quotes. The lookbehind assertion `(?<=\[\[.*)` tells it to include only cases where there is a `[[` anywhere behind, i.e. after the first instance of `[[`. Similarly, the lookahead assertion `(?=.*\]\])` tells it to include only cases where there is a `]]` anywhere ahead, i.e. before the last instance of `]]`.

I tested this using PowerShell. The exact syntax to do a global match and extract the first match groups of all the results will depend on the language.

Comment: Very well written and explained. I myself don't have much knowledge with regex and this helps (me) to understand it better, +1

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your RegEx Engine, you could use this pattern

```
(?:^.*?\[\[|\G[^"]*)("[^"]*")(?=.*\]\])
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/55)

Comment: This pattern will match `"abcd"]]` and it doesn't stop for this string: `[["abcd"]] "efgh"]]`

Comment: You're absolutely right, the assumption here is the input string has a balanced open and closed square brackets.