# php regex for detecting #number

Tags: php, regex

i have the following regex that i am trying to detect #x, x being a number. I was able to get it working when there is nothing around match 2, however if there is then it breaks. can someone help me with how to make this work both ways?

```
/(\G|\s+|^)#(\d+)((?=\s+)|(?=::)|$)/i
```

that will work with the line

```
This is a test #1234 end test
```

but that will not work with

```
This is a test #1234end test
This is a test#1234 end test
This is a test.#1234 end test
This is a test #1234. End test
```

anyone know what needs to be changed to achieve this?

edit, i am trying to allow anything but alphanumeric in the 3rd group, right now there is :: and whitespace. is there a way to combine these into 1 and not detect letters or numbers

Comment: Why not just use `/#(\d+)/`?

Comment: Your attempt suggests you have some negative cases.  What **don't** you want to match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(\G|\s+|^)#(\d+)((?=[^[:alnum:]])|$)
```

i wanted to keep the three groups that i had, but i only changed the 3rd group. i removed the :: and \S whitespace characters from the 3rd group and just added a simple NOT alphanumeric check, as this will contain those 2 conditions as well.

```
(\G|\s+|^)
#(\d+)
((?=[^[:alnum:]])|$)

[^[:alnum:]]
```

Comment: This answer is in the Low Quality Posts review queue because it's just code with no explanation. Please improve your answer by explaining what your code does and how it answers the question. Please read [this advice on answering programming questions helpfully](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx).

Comment: @AdiInbar As is this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/26759844/ this shouldn't give higher rep members any preferential treatment. Which that guy hardly ever gives any explanations in his answers.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm not quite sure what you're trying to say, but that's my stock comment when I encounter code-only answers in a LQP review. Some code-only answers by their nature don't really require explanation because it's self-evident how they resolve the problem, but I don't think that's the case here. Here's a recent example of my idea of how to answer a regex question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26575011/1248365. In any case, whether I leave this kind of review comment doesn't depend on how high the poster's rep is.

Comment: @AdiInbar I completely agree with you. Everyone benefits from having a well-explained answer since it educates us all and shows us the errors of our ways. Some answers are pretty obvious though when it comes to a simple syntax error, but for myself, I like to give detailed answers and to point out where the mistakes were made and how to instruct an OP on how to hopefully improve on certain techniques. As a saying goes: *"we can please some of the people some of the time, but we can't can't please all of the people all of the time"* lol - Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Running a preg match using `/#\d+/i` should get you what you are looking for. So running the following:

```
$items = [
    "This is a test #1234end test",
    "This is a test#1234 end test",
    "This is a test.#1234 end test",
    "This is a test #1234. End test"
];

foreach($items as $test){
    preg_match("/#\d+/i", $test, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

You will get this result:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "#1234"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "#1234"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "#1234"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "#1234"
}
```

If you don't want the `#` in the results, then you can then do a subpattern of `/#(\d+)/i`

Which will then result in the following:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "#1234"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "1234"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "#1234"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "1234"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "#1234"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "1234"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "#1234"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "1234"
}
```